# Looping through DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this is my function, it deletes people from a list if you click on certain part of the form:

```
function ParticipantsDeleteClick(model, url) {
for (i in model.Participants) {
    $("#delete" + i).click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: model.Participants[i].Id }),
            success: function (result) {
                result ? $("#participant" + i).remove() : alert("Delete failed");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Could not get a response from the server.");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

}

For some reason, it doesn't matter which person you click on, it will always delete the last person from the list. And it only works once because once the last "i" gets deleted, every other click function points to that dom element with the last i's value.

I don't know why every time I'm adding a click function it all points to the last i's value in the loop. I modified the function adding a temp variable that took i's integer value and that didn't work either:

```
function ParticipantsDeleteClick(model, url) {
for (i in model.Participants) {
    var temp = parseInt(i);
    $("#delete" + temp).click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: model.Participants[temp].Id }),
            success: function (result) {
                result ? $("#participant" + temp).remove() : alert("Delete failed");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Could not get a response from the server.");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

}

So I'm not sure how I can get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is always overwritten in the loop. You need a closure, eg by using `$.each(function(){..}`, or by wrapping the loop's body in a self-invoking function.

```
function ParticipantsDeleteClick(model, url) {

    $.each(model.Participants, function(i){ //The `function` creates a closure
        $("#delete" + i).click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: model.Participants[i].Id }),
                success: function (result) {
                    result ? $("#participant" + i).remove() : alert("Delete failed");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Could not get a response from the server.");
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to introduce a closure to capture the value of i each time around the loop. Using `$.each()` will introduce a closure for you (something like this)

```
function ParticipantsDeleteClick(model, url) {
    $.each(model.Participants, function(i,v) {
        $("#delete" + i).click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: model.Participants[i].Id }),
                success: function (result) {
                    result ? $("#participant" + i).remove() : alert("Delete failed");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Could not get a response from the server.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 scope levels here:

1. loop scope
2. click handler scope
3. ajax success handler scope

So you will need for each of those scope preserve and pass the variables. The [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method allows you to pass arguments to the callback from the outer scope and the `context` parameter allows you to pass parameters to the AJAX success callback. So:

```
$.each(model.Participants, function(index, participant) {
    var data = { index: index, participant: participant };
    $('#delete' + index).bind('click', data, function(evt) {
        // at this stage evt.data will point to what the data variable was pointing
        // from the outer scope but at the moment this handler was bound
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: evt.data.participant }),
            context: evt.data.index,
            success: function (result) {
                // since we have used the context parameter at this stage
                // this will point to this parameter which is simply the index
                result ? $('#participant' + this).remove() : alert('Delete failed');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Could not get a response from the server.');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Or to break this into separate functions to make it more clear:

```
function handleClick(evt) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: evt.data.participant }),
        context: evt.data.index,
        success: ajaxSuccess,
        error: ajaxError
    });
}

function ajaxSuccess(result) {
    result ? $('#participant' + this).remove() : alert('Delete failed');
}

function ajaxError() {
    alert('Could not get a response from the server.');
}
```

and then finally:

```
function ParticipantsDeleteClick(model, url) {
    $.each(model.Participants, function(index, participant) {
        var data = { index: index, participant: participant };
        $('#delete' + index).bind('click', data, handleClick);
    });
}
```